# Cocoa get the screen location on an NSMenu or NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to get the location (frame) of an `NSMenu` or one of the `NSMenuItems` inside it?

I have tried adding a custom view to one of the menu items and getting its frame, however it returns zero. All I need is the x coordinate, relative to the screen.

**Edit**

Calling `[[view window] frame]` on the `NSView` inside the `NSMenuItem` after the menu is visible works, however `window` is deprecated as of 10.6. I'll use this unless someone posts a better way...

Comment: Pretty sure that -[NSView window] isn't deprecated

Comment: @ChrisDevereux Yep, your correct, I was using Xcode quick help and it was showing `[NSCachedImageRep window]`. I this correct then? It seems arbitrary to me, and could change in future?